# SQL - Prepend a value if missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

**Code/data:**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
    (
        [Col1]   VARCHAR(20)
      , [RowNum] INT
    ) ;

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
    ( N'second', 1 )
  , ( N'fifth', 4 )
  , ( N'fourth', 3 )
    --, ( N'zzz', 1 )
  , ( N'third', 2 )

---- OR when "zzz" is part of this list
--VALUES
--     ( N'second', 2 )
--   , ( N'fifth', 5 )
--   , ( N'fourth', 4 )
--   , ( N'zzz', 1 )
--   , ( N'third', 3 )
SELECT  STUFF ((
                   SELECT   ',' + [SQ].[Col1]
                   FROM
                            (
                                SELECT  N'zzz' AS [Col1]
                                      , 1 AS [RowNum]
                                UNION
                                SELECT  [Col1]
                                      , [RowNum]
                                FROM    @T
                            ) AS [SQ]
                   FOR XML PATH ( '' ), TYPE
               ).[value] ( '.', 'varchar(MAX)' ), 1, 1, ''
              ) ;
```

**Current output:**

```
fifth,fourth,second,third,zzz
```

**Goal:**
Prepend "zzz," in the output string if missing in the 2nd part of the union AND the values should be in ASC ordered based on the values specified in [rownum] field defined in the 2nd part of the union. If "zzz" exists in the 2nd part of the input already (it will always be RowNum 1 in that case), it should return it only once as the first value.

**Expected output:**

```
zzz,second,third,fourth,fifth
```

UPDATED the requirement due to an error on my part when creating this post. Updated code/data represents more accurate scenario. Please note the RowNum seq in the 2nd part of the UNION, it also starts with 1, but this time, it might or might not be associated to "zzz" **Basically, I want to prepend "zzz" in the comma-delimited & ordered output if it doesn't exist.**

Comment: Add `ORDER BY RowNum` to your `FOR XML PATH` query. You don't supply an order, so SQL Server is free to put them in what ever order it "feels like".

Comment: Can you also add `1 as RowNum` to `SELECT  N'first' AS [Col1]` part?

Comment: You should explicitly state the issue(s) to be addressed, i.e. that the output order is not to your liking. Curiously, you solved the _conditional_ prepending issue by using `union` instead of `union all` since it eliminates duplicate rows.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. Based on the original code, your inputs were completely valid, but due to a mistake on my part when creating this post, I didn't post accurate scenario. Updated OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attached the Answer for the updated Scenario-

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
    (
        [Col1]   VARCHAR(20)
      , [RowNum] INT
    ) ;

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
    ( N'second', 1 )
  , ( N'fifth', 4 )
  , ( N'fourth', 3 )
    --, ( N'zzz', 1 )
  , ( N'third', 2 )

---- OR when "zzz" is part of this list
--VALUES
--     ( N'second', 2 )
--   , ( N'fifth', 5 )
--   , ( N'fourth', 4 )
--   , ( N'zzz', 1 )
--   , ( N'third', 3 )

SELECT  STUFF ((
                   SELECT   ',' + [SQ].[Col1]
                   FROM
                            (
                                SELECT  N'zzz' AS [Col1]
                                      , 0 AS [RowNum]
                                UNION
                                SELECT  [Col1]
                                      , [RowNum]
                                FROM    @T
                            ) AS [SQ]
                   ORDER BY [RowNum] 
                   FOR XML PATH ( '' ), TYPE
               ).[value] ( '.', 'varchar(MAX)' ), 1, 1, ''
              ) ;
```

**Returns**

***zzz,second,third,fourth,fifth***

Answer (score 2):

Hope the below one will help you.

```
               SELECT   ',' + [SQ].[Col1]
               FROM
                        (
                            SELECT  N'first' AS [Col1],1 AS [RowNum]
                            UNION
                            SELECT      [ABC].[Col1],[ABC].[RowNum]
                            FROM
                                        (
                                            VALUES
                                                ( N'second', 2 )
                                              , ( N'fifth', 5 )
                                              , ( N'fourth', 4 )
                                              --, ( N'first', 1 )
                                              , ( N'third', 3 )
                                        ) AS [ABC] ( [Col1], [RowNum] )
                        ) AS [SQ]
               ORDER BY [RowNum]
               FOR XML PATH ( '' ), TYPE
           ).[value] ( '.', 'varchar(MAX)' ), 1, 1, ''
          ) ;
```

**Returns an output**

**first,second,third,fourth,fifth**

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It solves the problem I originally posted. However, it was my mistake that I posted somewhat inaccurate scenario. With the updated scenario, is it possible to modify your code to fix it? I tried to play around with it and was unsuccessful. Thanks again! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Common Table Expressions (CTEs) provide a handy way of breaking queries down into simpler steps. Note that you can view the results of each step by switching out the last `select` statement.

```
with
  Assortment as (
    -- Start with the "input" rows.
    select Col1, RowNum
      from ( values ( N'second', 2 ), ( N'fifth', 5 ), ( N'fourth', 4 ),
        -- ( N'first', 1 ),
        ( N'third', 3 ) ) ABC ( Col1, RowNum ) ),
  ExtendedAssortment as (
    -- Conditionally add "first".
    select Col1, RowNum
      from Assortment
    union all -- Do not remove duplicate rows.
    select N'first', 1
      where not exists ( select 42 from Assortment where Col1 = N'first' ) )
  -- Output the result.
  --   Intermediate results may be seen by uncommenting one of the alternate   select   statements.
--  select * from Assortment;
--  select * from ExtendedAssortment;
  select Stuff(
    ( select N',' + Col1 from ExtendedAssortment order by RowNum for XML path(N''), type).value( N'.[1]', 'NVarChar(max)' ),
    1, 1, N'' ) as List;
```

The same logic can be performed using tables for input:

```
-- Rows to be included in the comma delimited string.
declare @Input as Table ( Col1 NVarChar(20), RowNum Int );
insert into @Input ( Col1, RowNum ) values
  ( N'second', 2 ), ( N'fifth', 5 ),
  --( N'ZZZ', 17 ), -- Test row.
  ( N'fourth', 4 ), ( N'third', 3 );
select * from @Input;

-- Mandatory value that must appear in the result.  One row only.
declare @Mandatory as Table ( Col1 NVarChar(20), RowNum Int );
-- By using the maximum negative value for an   Int   this value will be prepended
--   (unless other rows happen to have the same   RowNum   value).
insert into @Mandatory ( Col1, RowNum ) values ( N'ZZZ', -2147483648 );
select * from @Mandatory;

-- Process the data.
with
  AllRows as (
    select Col1, RowNum
      from @Input
    union all
    select Col1, RowNum
      from @Mandatory
      where not exists ( select 42 from @Mandatory as M inner join @Input as I on M.Col1 = I.Col1 ) )
  -- Output the result.
  --   Intermediate results may be seen by uncommenting the alternate   select   statement.
  --select * from AllRows;
  select Stuff(
    ( select N',' + Col1 from AllRows order by RowNum for XML path(N''), type).value( N'.[1]', 'NVarChar(max)' ),
    1, 1, N'' ) as List;
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It solves the problem I originally posted. However, it was my mistake that I posted somewhat inaccurate scenario. I'm going to play around with the updated scenario to see if this CTE approach works. Thanks again! Cheers

Comment: @007 You can replace `select N'first', 1` with the value you want to prepend and a number that will force it to the beginning of the list, be it `1`, `0` or `-2147483648` (-2^31). Change the `where not exists` value from `N'first'` to the value to be checked for in the input, e.g. `N'ZZZ'`, and Bob's your uncle. I've added a variation of the code to handle input from tables.